# JavaScript: Hex to decimal converter error

Tags: javascript, hex, decimal

I have been making a custom function for converting hex to decimal from my [scratch project](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/102878428/#player):

```
function Hex2Decimal(hex){
    var deci = 0;
    var num = 1;
    var hexstr = String(hex);
    hexstr = hexstr.toLowerCase();
    var expon = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < hex.length; i++){
        expon = Math.pow(16,hexstr.length - (num+1));
        if(hexstr[num+1] === "a"){
            deci = (10*expon)+deci;
        }else if(hexstr[num-1] === "b"){
            deci = (11*expon)+deci;
        }else if(hexstr[num-1] === "c"){
            deci = (12*expon)+deci;
        }else if(hexstr[num-1] === "d"){
            deci = (13*expon)+deci;
        }else if(hexstr[num-1] === "e"){
            deci = (14*expon)+deci;
        }else if(hexstr[num-1] === "f"){
            deci = (15*expon)+deci;
        }else if(hexstr[num-1] != "undefined"){
            deci = (Number(hexstr[num-1])*expon)+deci;
        }
        num = num + 1;
    }
    return deci;
}
```

but when I put "BC324240" into it, it returns the value '197338148' instead of '3157410368.'
When converting the value back to hex, I get 'BC32424.' For some reason, that I need help finding, the '0' in it is completely 'ignored.'
Also noticed that using '10' returns 1...

Comment: `i < hex.length - 1` should be `i < hex.length`. You are off by one.

Comment: I changed it, but the result was still the same. Nothing different.

Comment: Yeah, it's some funky code you've got there. I'm having a hard time making sense of what you are trying to do exactly. Can you add some comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the last position (the digit you should multiply by 16^0) because your call:

```
expon = Math.pow(16, hexstr.length - (num+1));
```

is off by one, should be:

```
expon = Math.pow(16, hexstr.length - num);
```

Answer (score 7):

The following built-in function will do the conversion for you:

```
dec = parseInt('0x' + hexstr,16);
```

Just be sure that the number to convert is less than the maximum safe JavaScript integer:
(2^53 - 1)  =   0x1fffffffffffff = 9007199254740991.

If you need to work with larger numbers, look at the code here:
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1620/arbitrary-base-conversion
I didn't write it, so don't ask me to explain it

Comment: Terse alternatives: `Number('0x' + hex)`, `+('0x' + hex)`, or ```+(`0x${hex}`)```. Same advice for big hex numbers, or just use `BigInt('0x' + hex).toString()`.

Comment: I believe the `'0x' + ` part is not needed, you can just use `dec = parseInt(hexstr, 16)`.